# Throws exception while Type casting from String to Int.

Tags: android, casting

I have no idea what is going wrong here.
Code Snippet

```
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String s1=SpinnerObj.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String n1=s1.substring(s1.indexOf("Rs")+2,s1.length()-1);
                int ns1=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n1));//Couldnt cast and throws Exception
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+ns1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),OrderPlaced.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
                catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "gg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }});
```

here i m trying to Type cast the String getting from Spinner to integer for computaions.

Comment: what value is getting in a n1?

Comment: add error logcat ...

Comment: Converting String to int is sometimes not possible when it has more than integers.It will throw exception.Try to use use String value and check once

Comment: Be sure there is no space or anyother string value in your n1 string, It must contains only numeric value. OR may be n1 value is null. Post logcat and your strings too to get more clear idea.

Comment: i have spinner value as "Havells fan(Rs 900)". and m getting 900 in n1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO you are taking incorrect first index of substring try below code

```
  String test = "Havells fan(Rs 900)";
        String n1=test.substring(test.indexOf("Rs")+3,test.length()-1);\\ use +3 instead of +2
        int ns1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n1));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+ns1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the string you gave in comments: `Havells fan(Rs 900)` you include a whitespace in your string while computing the starting index for the number because `s1.indexOf("Rs")+2`(this computation will give 14) will point to the whitespace (index 14), not to 9(index 15). For a proposed a solution, you can use any of the existing answers either trimming the string (`n1.trim()`) or counting the space char when you compute the starting index(`s1.indexOf("Rs")+3`).

Answer (score -1):

maybe the string has a space.
you should use `n1.trim()`